# How can I echo the variables properly using foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 foreach loop which gets colors and sizes. I also have for loop which generate the material number. I'm trying to achieve distribute the variables well for example I have 2 colors with 3 sizes.
This is the desired output

```
Material#  | Color | Size

1001       | Blue  | Small

2001       | Blue  | Medium

3001       | Blue  | Large

4001       | Green | Small

5001       | Green | Medium

6001       | Green | Large
```

Here's my code:

```
//insert material number
for($x = 1; $x <= $matnumbersize; $x++ )
{

    $matnummm=    str_pad($x, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $materialnumber = $newgennumber.$matnummm;

    $matnumberr[] = $materialnumber; //materialnumber

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO materialnumber(productID,stylecodeID,genericnumberID,materialnumber) VALUES(:pid,:scode,:gcode,:matnum)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $productID, ':scode' => $styleID, ':gcode' => $gennumID, ':matnum' => $materialnumber));
}    

print_r($matnumberr);  

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcolor a,  color b where a.productID = :pid and a.colorID = b.colorID ");
$statement->execute(array(':pid' => "$productID"));

foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row)
{
    $colorcode = $row['colorCode'];


    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productsizes where productID = :pid ");
    $statement->execute(array(':pid' => "$productID"));
    foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row)
    {
        $sizeCde = $row['sizeName'];
        echo $colorcode.$sizeCde.'<br/>';

    }
}
```

I tried my best but I cant think a fix of it. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use pastebin etc. Include the minimum required code to reproduce what you have tried so far and what doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry sir anyway I fixed it will include my answer here

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and manage to make it shorter so here's my code

```
    $y = 1;
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcolor a,  color b where a.productID = :pid and a.colorID = b.colorID ");
 $statement->execute(array(':pid' => "$productID"));

 foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row)
 {
  $colorcode = $row['colorCode'];

 $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productsizes where productID = :pid ");
 $statement->execute(array(':pid' => "$productID"));
foreach ($statement->fetchAll() as $row)
 {
    $sizeCde = $row['sizeName'];
echo $colorcode.$sizeCde.'<br/>';  

$yy=    str_pad($y, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$newmaterialnum = $newgennumber.$yy;

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO materialnumber(productID,stylecodeID,genericnumberID,materialnumber,color,size) 
 VALUES(:pid,:scode,:gcode,:matnum,:color,:size)");
  $stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $productID, ':scode' => $styleID, ':gcode' => $gennumID, ':matnum' => $newmaterialnum,
  ':color' => $colorcode, ':size' => $sizeCde));


$y++;

}
}
```